# Run cucumber .feature file through ERB preprocessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, erb

I get that there's not existing support for variables in Cucumber `.feature` files, but if  I could run them through a ERB preprocessor there'd be no need.

I'd like to be able to make a file like `my_tests.feature.erb`:

```
Feature: Do something
Scenario: Thing
  When I have the secret password <%= ENV["PASSWORD"] %>
  Then my credentials are valid
```

I've written a quick solution here:

```
require 'erb'

Dir.glob("./*.feature.erb").each do |path|
  erb = File.read path
  result = ERB.new(erb).result(binding)
  new_path = path.gsub(".feature.erb", ".feature")
  File.open(new_path, 'w') do |f|
    f.write result
  end
end
```

I'm wondering if there's something already out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why on earth would you do this when you can just write

```
When 'I use the secret password'
```

and have your step definition call code to get the password. By adding an extra pre-processing step you are making your whole test suite much more complex and fragile.

There is never any need for the language of scenarios to get information about how to do something from external sources. You can always push that requirement down into step definitions and supporting code.

Comment: I've seen similar things said on other questions asking about variables in Cucumber. I suppose I see things a little differently. Yes, it is certainly possible to put the variables in step definitions, and probably this is what Cucumber recommends and officially supports. But when it comes down to it I just really enjoy writing my 'code' in human readable sentences.

Comment: `When I have the secret password <%= ENV["PASSWORD"] %>` is more human readable than `When I use the secret password`!! Scenarios are not for coding, they are for describing behaviour. Of course its your choice what you do, but there are good reasons why coding in scenarios is so strongly discouraged by Cukes.